# How to copy files from multiple directories?

Tags: command-line

I have a bunch of text files in several directories I want to copy into another.
What can I do, instead of going inside each directory and `cp *.txt` in this directory?

Comment: no because my files are located in multiple folders and I want to copy them to another

Comment: @bigTree Are the folders themselves in the same parent directory?

Comment: I think this answer could be merged with the other question.

Comment: @minerz029 yes they are

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If none of the answers in the related threads is what you're looking for, you could consider using the `find` command, which will search directories recursively downwards from a given parent. You can specify an `exec` action to perform on each of the matching files that it finds - in this case, you'd want it to perform a `cp` to a new target directory

```
find /path/to/parent -name '*.txt' -exec cp -t /path/to/newdir {} +
```

The `{}` is replaced by the files that it locates, and the `+` at the end causes it to batch them so as not to overflow the maximum number of arguments that `cp` can handle in one command. The `newdir` must already exist.

Since you are moving files from many places to one place, there is a possibility that some names will be non-unique, and so you may want to take care to prevent an earlier copy from being overwritten by a later copy - you can do that by adding a `backup` option

```
find /path/to/parent -name '*.txt' -exec cp --backup=numbered -t /path/to/newdir {} +
```

which will add a simple numbered suffix to each duplicate file. You can add a `-v` or `--verbose` flag to the `cp` if you want to see a running report of the files as it copies them.